# Homebrew python taking precedence over venv python

Tags: python-3.x, homebrew, python-venv

I have a few questions related to Python paths. I used homebrew to install python3 on my Mac:

```
# homebrew python
> which -a python
python: aliased to /usr/local/bin/python3.9

# system python
❯ which -a python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
```

I then set up a virtual environment using the command `python -m venv venv`. After activating it, I get:

```
> which -a python
python: aliased to /usr/local/bin/python3.9
/Users/kshitijsachan/Documents/venv/bin/python

> which -a python3
/Users/kshitijsachan/Documents/venv/bin/python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
```

My questions are:

1. Why does homebrew python take precedence over the venv python when I run `which -a python` with the venv activated?
2. Why is `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3` listed twice under `which -a python3`?
3. Is this the canonical setup for venv's with Homebrew python?